# How can I define a default/else route in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, routes, symfony4

I define my routes like this:

```
// config/routes.yaml

index:
    path: /
    controller: App\Controller\IndexController::index
news:
    path: /news/{slug}
    controller: App\Controller\PageNewsController::show
```

If none of those routes matches, I would like to load a default controller, or redirect, or whatever. But how do I define such a default route?

```
allOthers:
    path: * <-- WHAT#HAS#TO#BE#PUT#HERE
    controller: App\Controller\ElseController::show
```

I rather want to avoid to work with annotations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can make default route and call when no route matches. You can do as following way:

```
allOthers:
    path: /{regpattern}
    controller: App\Controller\ElseController::show      
    requirements:
        regpattern: ".+"
```

Comment: Thank you, this works - but I had to rename "reg-pattern" into "regpattern".

Comment: Yes, it just example. you can change it as per your requirement.